# code coverage tool from Visual Studio 2012 Team Tools does not work on release bits

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

When I try to run codecoverage tool on release bits of my website I get an empty .coverage file containing the following error:

*Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731*

This issue does not occur if I run it on the debug version of the same build.

These are the exact steps I perform:
- start monitoring code coverage on IIS server
codecoverage collect /IIS /session:test /output:test.coverage
- perform a few click around the website
- stop monitoring code coverage 
codecoverage shutdown /session:test

Note! I do hae the .pdb files in the same place as the binaries.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Cristina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get to the bottom of this. For the release build, there were 2 things I needed to change in the .config file

- specify the path to the Symbols (apparently this is needed even if the .pdf files are in the same location as the dlls)
- I had to remove the default  exclusion list since these included Microsoft public key tokens and our product is a Microsoft product.

Hope this will be helpful for others running into the same situation.

Regards,

Cristina

Comment: Weird, it should be checking the same directory that the module loaded from for the .pdbs (source: I wrote the tool a few years ago before leaving MSFT).  As for the PKT issue, yeah if you're working on a Microsoft product you should remove those exclusions (you can also manually include your specific modules as well).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Enabling Profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5ec0es1.aspx).

**[UPDATE 5 Jun 2013 14:04:00-04:00 UTC]**
I also found this article that you may be interested in: [Application Analytics: What Every Developer Should Know](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620913.aspx).

As far as Code Coverage is concerned, I didn't see anything specific to using the VS Code Coverage tool and configuring for IIS. I did see lots of articles about testing web applications in general, some of which involved setting up code coverage ([Setting Up Machines and Collecting Diagnostic Information Using Test Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286743.aspx) being an example).

Sorry I couldn't be of more help to you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; however I was looking into making codecoverage tool that is shipped with Visual Studio 2012 work :)
Any ideas on this?